# OpenGL ES についてobjファイルに起きたエラー

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es

初の質問で拙いですがよろしくお願いします

Eclipse lunaでOpengl esを使用してのAndroidアプリを開発していたのですが、Linux環境からMacに開発中のプロジェクトを移したところ、今まで上手くいっていた3Dオブジェクトの表示が出来なくなりました。(正しく言うとアプリが落ちます)
3Dを使わなければ全く問題なく表示されるので、原因を探してみたところaseetsの中にあるobjファイルのコードに赤い点線が引かれていました

objファイルの方はmtllibのところに
mtlファイルにはほとんどです

解決方法を教えていただければ幸いです

追記:
objファイルのコードの頭です

```
# WaveFront *.obj file (generated by Cheetah3D)

mtllib droid.mtl

g body
v 0.000000 0.458228 0.000000
v 0.000000 0.458228 0.500000...
```

上記のコードのmtllibに赤線が引かれます
mtlファイルはこちらです

```
# WaveFront *.mtl file (generated by Cheetah3D)

newmtl default
Ns 64
Kd 0.700 0.700 0.700
Ks 1.000 1.000 1.000
Ka 0.700 0.700 0.700

newmtl green
Ns 64.000000
Tr 1.000000
Kd 0.604681 0.839195 0.205600
Ks 0.990051 1.000000 0.414934
Ka 0.604681 0.839195 0.205600

newmtl white
Ns 64.000000
Tr 1.000000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ks 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
```

mtlファイルは数字意外のほとんどが赤線になっています
私はここが原因だと思うのですが、もしかしたら違うんですかね